# What edition of Traveller is this?

Tags: product-identification, traveller

I have an PDF of a Traveller core rulebook, but I can’t seem to figure out what edition it is. There is a character sheet in the back, but I haven’t been able to find the sheet anywhere else.

The cover looks like this:
[image]

And the Character Sheet looks like this:

[image]

Here is the copyright page:

[image]

I haven’t been able to find a definite publication date.

Comment: PDF didn't scan the copyright page, eh?

Comment: @ZeissIkon the copyright page is there, but it says both classic traveller and mongoose traveller, as well as saying Traveller is copyright 2008 but I am not sure if that is a renewal of overall copright on traveller, or the specific edition copright

Comment: The newest date you see there should be the publication date of the edition you have.  Perhaps include a shot of that copyright page?

Comment: @ZeissIkon done

Comment: I don't know how many editions there have been since then, but what I think of as classic Traveller never had a single "Core Rulebook". There was a set of three (IIRC) 5x8 booklets that provided the core rules.

Comment: @The Photon - yes and no, there were also reprints in a larger form factor from Marc Miller. On the other hand, they didn't have the things you can observe in the character sheet which tells me it is some flavour of Mongoose Traveller.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right there, top of the box at the bottom of the copyright page, "Traveller (C) 2008 by Mongoose Publications."  You have the 2008 edition of Mongoose *Traveller*.  References to original *Traveller* (GDW version) are there as credit to prior work.

There may be another page, usually facing this one or on the back of it, giving printing history, conceivably edition history as well if there were multiple editions of this version of the game -- but the original publication of this (Mongoose) *Traveller Core Rule Book* was 2008.

Comment: Alright thanks. Any idea why googling mongoose traveller character sheet fails to yield this sheet?

Comment: I'd guess because they omitted the "permission to copy" statement often found on example sheets in rule books.